# django: simple contact form not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to set up a contact form, and have temporarily tried to get it to display the fields that were submitted when the submit button is hit (same page). When I click submit, it reloads with the contact form showing. So, here's my view:

```
from website.forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):

    Success = False
    email = ""
    title = ""
    text = ""

    if request.method == "POST":    
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if contact_form.is_valid():
            Success = True
            email = contact_form.cleaned_data['email']
            title = contact_form.cleaned_data['title']
            text = contact_form.cleaned_data['text']

    else:
        contact_form = ContactForm()

    ctx = {'contact_form':contact_form, 'email':email, 'title':title, 'text':text, 'success':success}

    return render_to_response('website/contact.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here's forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    title = forms.CharField()
    text = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )
```

And here's the template:

```
{% if success %}

    <p>{{ email }}</p>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
    <p>{{ text }}</p>

{% else %}

    <form action"." method="POST">

    {{ contact_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </form>
{% endif %}
```

It seems very simple, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that Success != success... you have to type variables with the right case... check also the output of {{success}} (It should be "None" or anyway not a boolean)

Comment: what, this site has timers? ;-)